# How to manipulate a count matrix from a DGEList?

Tags: r

I am currently doing an RNASeq differential expression analysis. I used the function `DGEList` from `edgeR` to obtain the `count` and `sample` objects. I now want to remove a list of genes from `count`. This is the code I tried (with `remove` the list of genes I want to remove, `gene` the reference fo all genes I have):

```
n=0
for (i in remove) {
    for (j in gene) {
        n=(n+1)
        if (i==j) {
            counts=counts[-n, ]
            n=(n-1)
        }
        if (n==nrow(counts)) {
            n=0
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to work as it does properly on a matrix that is similar.The code is still running while the one working on the matrix finished a long time ago. It should remove about 16000 rows.

Do I have to manipulate it in a different way ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read on how to provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. However, I can tell you that there are many easier ways of accomplishing what you want. For starters, R is a vectorial programming language and there's no need to use loops for accessing data. It makes code hard to read and it's incredibly inefficient in a language like R. As for the DGE-list, you should read the help for subsetting in edgeR: `library(edgeR); ? subsetting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter out some genes from your count matrix. In that case instead of the loops, you could try indexing the `counts` object. Assuming the entries in `diff` match some entries in `rownames(counts)`, you could try:

`counts_subset <- counts_all[which(!rownames(counts_all) %in% diff),]`

A similar approach should work on the table obtained by running the LRT test (`result$table`). This would be better object to filter.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly fine and is way more faster. I have to think about this `wich` function. My loop above does finish after a long time but it does not provide a valid result.